# GCP ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, startup

My GCE VM instance seems to be stuck at startup (startup-script doesn't launch). I tried to connect to it as usual with gcloud, SSH (on the console and with my macOS) but no chance. I also tried to debug it with serial port but they are asking login/password and I never set one.

While debugging the serial port I saw this error message:

`ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>.`

I tried to remove every metadata from this project without success neither.

Finally I did all this troubleshooting https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/vm-startup?hl=en and couldn't find any issue with the disk.

OS is an old Debian distrib (8.7) and I got other VMs working fine within this network, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a root password for the serial console, use the following startup script to add it to your instance :

1. Go to the VM instances page in Google Cloud Platform console.
2. Click on the instance for which you want to add a startup script.
3. Click the Edit button at the top of the page.
4. Click on ‘Enable [connecting to serial ports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console#disabling_interactive_serial_console_access_through_organization_policy)’
5. Under Custom metadata, click Add item.
6. Set 'Key' to 'startup-script' and set 'Value' to this script:

#! /bin/bash

echo root:PASSWORD

7. Click Save and then click RESET on the top of the page. You might need to wait for some time for the instance to reboot.
8. Click on 'Connect to serial port' on the page.
9. In the new window, you might need to wait a bit and press ‘Enter’ on your keyboard once; then, you should see the login prompt.
10. Login using the root and PASSWORD you provided.

Please also note that once you reset your password, please remove the custom metadata entered otherwise it will execute every time your instance reboots.

Also suggests you to check the [Routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes), [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts), [forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications) .

Comment: As I was saying in my initial post, startup-script doesn't launch unfortunately.

Comment: The Possibility for this error to occur is when the GCE guest environment is not set up correctly. GCE linux VM has daemons running which are responsible for setting the guestenvironment(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#update-guest). You need to make sure those scripts are running on your VM. You can use ps -aux | grep google_ command to confirm. This document(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#daemons)  has more information about setting Linux guest environments.

Comment: Check for validating the guestenvironmen(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei). Another way to fix this would be restarting your VM which will start the GCE scripts during the boot process.